# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on unserialized Array Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

I was trying to do foreach on an array data from a string (serialized Array) in Laravel Blade. I applied on the other Blade it works well, but not on this one.

I tried to use **for** and works, but still curious where is the error on this code.

**My Array on var_dump($buktis)**

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(57) "stringA" [1]=> string(57) "stringB" [2]=> string(57) "stringC" }
```

**My Code**

```
@php $buktis = unserialize($rqslsai->bukti_server); @endphp
@foreach($buktis as $bukti)
     <a>{{ $bukti }}</a><br>
@endforeach
```

**Error Image**

[The error message on Laravel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28vVI.png)

Comment: You are getting any error?

Comment: Yes, here is the error image https://i.stack.imgur.com/28vVI.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error says **$buktis** is not a valid argument (collection or array), so there must something didn't go as expected during the serialization, try `dd($buktis)` right before your foreach. It should let you know what's wrong your variable and then you'll be able to fix the code.

Comment: I got this ( [https://imgur.com/m6AVhEQ](https://imgur.com/m6AVhEQ) ) on `dd($bukis)`. The code seems fine, but I got error from nowhere.

Comment: Still getting the same error on that line? The array looks perfect to me, are you sure you don't have a case where that $buktis is a different datatype or maybe null  and that's when it throws that error?

Comment: I tried multiple times, and it still gave me error. Even tho i tried to clear cache and compiled view cache on Laravel.